# Existence of an Entire Function When Given Real Element

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

We have $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$

is there exists entire function $f(z)$ such that
$$Re(f(z))=e^x(xcos(y)-ysin(y))+2sin(x)sinh(y)+x^3-3xy^2+y$$

i already tried it like this:

$$Re(f(z))=u(x,y)\\u_x(x,y)=e^x(xcos(y)-ysin(y)+cos(y))+2cos(x)sinh(y)+3x^2-3y^2\\u_y(x,y)=e^x(-xsin(y)-sin(y)-ycos(y))+2sin(x)cosh(y)-6xy+1$$

i know from the C-R, the function is entire when $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, so i did it and integrate the $v_x$ and $v_y$.

$v=2cosh(y)cos(x)+(xsin(y)+ycos(y))e^x+3yx^2-x+C$ and $v=2cosh(y)cos(x)+(xsin(y)+ycos(y))e^x+3yx^2-y^3+C$

so what is the conclusion? does the entire function $f(z)$ exists when $x=y^3$?

Comment: Remember when you integrate a partial derivative, not only will a constant vanish, but actually *any function* of the other variables. So your $C$ in the first equation should really be an $f(y),$ and the second equation should have an $f(x).$

Comment: oh right, so it will be $f(y)-f(x)=y^3-x$ right? but then what should i do?

Comment: First off, this is kind of my fault but I should clarify that they are different functions, so let's say $f(x)$ and $g(y).$ Second off, I think that should be $-y^3 + x.$ Now, if this holds for all $x,y$, then the expressions in terms of $x$ have to match on both sides, so $f(x) = -x + C$ and $g(y) = -y^3 - C$.

Comment: oh yes right, no it's okay it's kind of my fault because i was wrong about the integration of partial derivative. But what i don't understand is what's the conclusion after the $f(x)$ and $g(y)$?

Comment: Well then you can plug those into your forms for $v$ to see that they agree, which gives you your general form for $v.$

Comment: ah thank you very much, i understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

$$v=2cosh(y)cos(x)+(xsin(y)+ycos(y))e^x+3yx^2−y^3-x+C$$ is the answer, so the complete answer will be:

$$f(z)=e^x(xcos(y)−ysin(y))+2sin(x)sinh(y)+x^3−3xy^2+y+i(2cosh(y)cos(x)+(xsin(y)+ycos(y))e^x+3yx^2−y^3-x+C)$$